# PHP: Why doesn't my code Insert to database

Tags: php, html, forms, oracle

I'm working on a senior project and I have been developing a site that uses PHP to read/write data from a database. I can read data successfully to the site but when it comes to writing data, I'm having trouble populating my Oracle database with the form data that is on the site. Assume that the connection is correct because that's the same connection I use to read data and it works.

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    // Add validation code here

    // Variable definition -- student info
    $varOrg = $_POST['orgdept'];
    $varFirst = $_POST['first'];
    $varLast = $_POST['last'];
    $varUID = $_POST['uid'];
    $varStudentEmail = $_POST['semail'];
    $varPhone = $_POST['sphone'];
    $varOrgEmail = $_POST['orgemail'];
    $varAdvisorName = $_POST['advisorname'];


    // Variable definition -- event info
    $varEventName = $_POST['eventname'];
    $varEventDate = $_POST['eventDate'];
    $varStartTime = $_POST['startTime'];
    $varEndTime = $_POST['endTime'];
    $varAttendance = $_POST['attendance'];
    $varOpenTo = $_POST['opento'];

    // ADD code for recurring dates

    // Variable definition -- event logistics
    $varEventType = $_POST['eventtype'];
    $varOtherType = $_POST['othertypein'];
    $varLocation = $_POST['locationselect'];
    $varOtherIN = $_POST['inother1'];
    $varPrefRoom1 = $_POST['proom1'];
    $varPrefRoom2 = $_POST['proom2'];
    $varOtherOUT = $_POST['outother1'];
    $varDMNecess = $_POST['dmnecess'];
    $varDMPowerON = $_POST['poweron'];
    $varDMPowerOFF = $_POST['poweroff'];
    $varDescription = $_POST['description'];

    // Variable definition - add'l necessities
    $varAmpSoundDesc = $_POST['ampsound'];
    $varSecurityDesc = $_POST['security'];
    $varFoodDesc = $_POST['food'];
    $varChildrenDesc = $_POST['children'];
    $varElectricityDesc = $_POST['electricity'];
    $varSponsorshipDesc = $_POST['sponsorship'];

    // Variable definition - signature/date
    $varSignature = $_POST['signature'];
    $varSignDate = $_POST['signdate'];

    $db = oci_connect('ASSUME CORRECT');
    if (!$db) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        die("Error connecting to the database.");   
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT(EVENT_ID, STATUS, GROUP_NAME, STUDENTID, CONTACT_FIRST, CONTACT_LAST, EMAIL, PHONE, EVENT_NAME, EVENT_START, EVENT_END, ATTENDANCE, E_LOCATION, EVENT_TYPE, E_DESCRIPTION, EVENT_DATE) ' .
        'VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL, 'PENDING', :groupname, :studentid, :first, :last, :email, :phone, :eventname, to_date(:eventstart, 'HH24:MI'), to_date(:eventend, 'HH24:MI'), :attendance, :location, :eventtype, :description, to_date(:eventdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')); ";

        $compiled = oci_parse($db, $sql);

        oci_bind_by_name($complied, ':groupname', $varOrg);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':studentid', $varUID);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':first', $varFirst);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':last', $varLast);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':email', $varStudentEmail);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':phone', $varPhone);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':eventname', $varEventName);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':eventstart', $varStartTime);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':eventend', $varEndTime);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':attendance', $varAttendance);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':location', $varLocation);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':eventtype', $varEventType);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':description', $varDescription);
        oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':eventdate', $varEventDate);

        oci_execute($compiled);
    }   
}
?>
```

I've added name attributes to all of my controls but it doesn't get me anything to publish to the database. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: What is happening when you send the form data? Do you get an error? Does it always fail or only with some types of values in the form data?

Comment: have you get any error???

Comment: You're not checking for errors via PHP. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Most likely as the answer below states, would have caught the variable mismatch. You should also check for errors in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in one of your variables.

```
oci_bind_by_name($complied, ':groupname', $varOrg);
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

where it should read as `$compiled`

```
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':groupname', $varOrg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Sql query properly

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT(EVENT_ID, STATUS, GROUP_NAME, STUDENTID, CONTACT_FIRST, CONTACT_LAST, EMAIL, PHONE, EVENT_NAME, EVENT_START, EVENT_END, ATTENDANCE, E_LOCATION, EVENT_TYPE, E_DESCRIPTION, EVENT_DATE) 
        VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL, 'PENDING', :groupname, :studentid, :first, :last, :email, :phone, :eventname, to_date(:eventstart, 'HH24:MI'), to_date(:eventend, 'HH24:MI'), :attendance, :location, :eventtype, :description, to_date(:eventdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')); ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this line of your code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT(EVENT_ID, STATUS, GROUP_NAME, STUDENTID, CONTACT_FIRST, CONTACT_LAST, EMAIL, PHONE, EVENT_NAME, EVENT_START, EVENT_END, ATTENDANCE, E_LOCATION, EVENT_TYPE, E_DESCRIPTION, EVENT_DATE) ' .
    'VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL, 'PENDING', :groupname, :studentid, :first, :last, :email, :phone, :eventname, to_date(:eventstart, 'HH24:MI'), to_date(:eventend, 'HH24:MI'), :attendance, :location, :eventtype, :description, to_date(:eventdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')); ";
```

You open the `$sql` string with double quotes on the first line, and close it with single quotes. And on the concatenating line, you open it with single quotes, and close it with double quotes.

Replace it with this instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT(EVENT_ID, STATUS, GROUP_NAME, STUDENTID, CONTACT_FIRST, CONTACT_LAST, EMAIL, PHONE, EVENT_NAME, EVENT_START, EVENT_END, ATTENDANCE, E_LOCATION, EVENT_TYPE, E_DESCRIPTION, EVENT_DATE) " .
    "VALUES (SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL, 'PENDING', :groupname, :studentid, :first, :last, :email, :phone, :eventname, to_date(:eventstart, 'HH24:MI'), to_date(:eventend, 'HH24:MI'), :attendance, :location, :eventtype, :description, to_date(:eventdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')); ";
```

Check out this line, too :

```
 oci_bind_by_name($complied, ':groupname', $varOrg);
```

You misspelt `compiled` as `complied`.

replace with this:

```
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':groupname', $varOrg);
```